# How to match the innermost parenthesis set using Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the innermost sub-string for () in the below string using Python:

```
x = "a (b) (c (d) e"
```

what I want below sub-string as output

```
(d)
```

what I tried till now is as below

```
re.findall(r"\(.*?\)", x)
re.findall(r"\(.*\)", x)
```

but it gives me output as the outer strings and that is not useful.
I want to match the innermost string which is available between `(  )`.
This example is part of another complex string and this string aptly displays my issue. I require the regex solution only with the parentheses.

Comment: You probably need to post more example strings. How is d the "innermost" string? I see an open `(` before c but no closing `)` so in your example b and d are the same depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex I use for this purpose are:

```
(\([^\(]*?\))
```

And here's it demonstrated at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V2Im9h/1)

i.e.

```
groups = [m for m in re.finditer(r"(\([^\(]*?\))",text)]
```

This returns all deepest-level bracketed groups in a string.

For example the string:

*"(Mary ( had a (little) ) lamb)"*

This regex returns *"(little)"*.

In strings that contain separately bracketed sections, the regex will return all groups that are most deeply nested in their own locale.

e.g.

*"(its) fleece (as (white) ) as snow."*

Would return two groups, *"(its)"* and *"(white)"*

I use this for tokenising bracketed logic statements, and by tokenising only the deepest nested clauses at a time, replacing them with flattened tokens, I can iteratively parse an entire logic statement, until no remaining brackets are found.

It's worth ensuring the statement being parsed has all its brackets matched - e.g. in your opening statement, `x = "a (b) (c (d) e"` there's a missing bracket at the end - and should be closed off with a final `)`, such as `x = "a (b) (c (d) e)"`.